# Runtime validation of jOOQ generated classes and actual DB schema

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I need to check on application startup that DB schema which is currently in DB and schema which was used for previously JOOQ generated models are the same. 
I tried to use solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14102613/3007501) and found some problems:

1. **A trick querying all the tables**: this solutions don't check column  types, only table and field names but i need to check types too.
2. `MY_SCHEMA.getTables().equals(create.meta().getTables())`: Only schema and name is checked here, not column types again.

I tried to use information available in `create.meta().getTables()` and do  the comparison manually but encountered another problem. DataTypes for generated fields and fields retrieved in runtime from `create.meta()` don't match in some cases.

Example is `"time" timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now()` field which has `length`, `precision`, `scale` values and doesn't have `defaultValue` value in runtime JOOQ field but doesn't have them in generated JOOQ field and has `defaultValue` instead.

Is it correct behavior for JOOQ? Metadata extracted with `create.meta()` and metadata from generated schema can't be used for comparison as is. Is there any other ways to do this correctly?

For tests were used:
PostgreSQL 9.5.3 with JDBC 9.4.1208 driver,
JOOQ 3.8.2,
Java 8

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, there is (unfortunately) a slight difference between the generated code (more complete) and what is delivered by `org.jooq.Meta` (less complete) because the latter internally depends on JDBC's `DatabaseMetaData`, which isn't always implemented correctly/completely.

One way to solve your problem would be to compare generated code with the output from jOOQ-meta, the library that is used by the jOOQ code generator. It would be significantly more manual coding work, but that's as good as it gets for your use-case as of jOOQ 3.8.

Another workaround (more of a hack) would be to compare the generated Java code with a fresh re-generation on a file system level (like git diff). I'm not sure if that approach does the trick for you.